# Why does changing the order of two CSS rules change my results?

Tags: css

Why does changing the order of two CSS rules change my results? When I use this it gives me a border that I do not want. This produces the wrong result that I'm going for:

```
.menuBar .navbar-nav > li > a::after, .menuBar .navbar-nav > li.active > a::after {
    background-color: #00c4ff;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 0;
}
.menuBar .navbar-nav > li > a:hover::after, .menuBar .navbar-nav > li.active > a::after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

But if I just change the order of these two CSS rules, then it gives me right result. So what's happening here?

```
.menuBar .navbar-nav > li > a:hover::after, .menuBar .navbar-nav > li.active > a::after {
    width: 100%;
}

.menuBar .navbar-nav > li > a::after, .menuBar .navbar-nav > li.active > a::after {
    background-color: #00c4ff;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 0;
}
```

[image]

This is my markup

```
<div class="menuBar jumplinks">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button aria-expanded="false" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#portfolio">Work</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML too?

Comment: Can you maybe make a fiddle. Seems to me, you don't need ::after for this.

Why not something like: a {padding-bottom:3px;} a:hover {border-bottom: 2px cyan solid; padding-bottom:1px;}

Comment: Why does changing the order change the result? Well... if you paint your car, first white, then black; you'll get a different result than if you do it in the opposite order. That's what the C stands for : cascading. Ie. later rules trump earlier rules (of the same specificity)

Comment: Of course, i share. You can check it now

Answer (score 0):

Because both of them contain a setting for `width`, one changes `width` to `0`;

```
.menuBar .navbar-nav > li > a::after, .menuBar .navbar-nav > li.active > a::after {
    background-color: #00c4ff;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 0; /* <------------------------- THIS LINE */
}
```

And another one changes `width` to `100%`;

```
.menuBar .navbar-nav > li > a:hover::after, .menuBar .navbar-nav > li.active > a::after {
    width: 100%; /* <------------------------- THIS LINE */
}
```

The reason the appearance is changing is that it's reading what comes before, then after, linearly down the file. This means when it reads `width: 100%;` the `width` property will be `100%` but when it gets to `width: 0;` it changes the `width`  to `0`.

Hope this helps! :)